# Detect if something is Enumerable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a method that accepts either a single object or a collection of objects. What is the proper way of detecting if what's passed in is Enumerable? I'm currently doing the following (which works but I'm not sure it's the correct way):

```
def foo(bar)
  if bar.respond_to? :map
    # loop over it
  else
    # single object
  end
end
```

Comment: `respond_to? :each` is probably closer to what you want.

Answer (score 8):

I would use `is_a?`.

```
bar.is_a? Enumerable
```

But there’s a better way to take a single object or a collection, assuming that the caller knows which one they’re passing in. Use a splat:

```
def foo(*args)
  args.each do |arg|
    …
  end
end
```

Then you can call it as `foo(single_arg)`, `foo(arg1, arg2)`, and `foo(*argv)`.

Comment: This won't work for objects that pretends to be enumerable but only implements a subset of its methods, e.g. only an `each` or `map` but doesn't actually includes the `Enumerable` module.

Comment: Your new method is slightly different. If passed an array, `args` will be `[[elem1, elem2, elem3]]`.

Answer (score 4):

I depends on your exact needs, but it's usually not a great idea to differentiate between a single object and an `Enumerable`. In particular, a `Hash` is an `Enumerable`, but in most cases it should be considered as a single object.

It's usually better to distinguish between a single object and an *array-like* argument. That's what Ruby often does. The best way to do this is to check if `arg.respond_to? :to_ary`. If it does, then all methods of `Array` should be available to you, if not treat it as a single object.

If you really want to check for `Enumerable`, you could test `arg.is_a? Enumerable` but consider that a `Hash` is an `Enumerable` and so are `Lazy` enumerators (and calling `map` on them won't even give you an array!)

Answer (score 3):

If your purpose is to loop over it, then the standard way is to ensure it is an array. You can do it like this without condition.

```
def foo(bar)
  [*bar] # Loop over it. It is ensured to be an array.
end
```

Comment: In this case that's what I'm doing but I would also like to know the best/preferred way to determine if something is Enumerable

Answer (score 1):

What about handling single items or a collection in one shot?

```
[*bar].each { |item| puts item }
```

This will work whether `bar` is a single item or an array or hash or whatever.  This probably isn't the best for working with hashes, but with arrays it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to ensure that something is an `Array` is with the [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) "function (technically still a method):

```
def foo(bar)
  Array(bar).map { |o| … }
end
```

`Array` will leave an array an array, and convert single elements to an array:

```
Array(["foo"]) # => ["foo"]
Array("foo")   # => ["foo"]
Array(nil)     # => []
```